# Read file & render as HTTP response using Mule

Tags: file, mule, mule-component

In mule, I have very simple requirement that on receiving HTTP request, a file needs to be read and rendered as HTTP response. If i use Mule's File(Inbound) the file is being kept polled, not serving the exact purpose. This can be achieved using Java component of Mule, can this achieved through simple mule components rather than Java component.

My flow looks like below:

```
<flow name="copyFile" doc:name="copyFile">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8091" path="fetchXsd" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <flow-ref name="readflow" doc:name="Flow Reference"/>
</flow>
<flow name="readflow" doc:name="readflow">
     <file:inbound-endpoint path="src/main/resources" connector-ref="input" doc:name="File" >
        <file:filename-wildcard-filter pattern="*.xsd" caseSensitive="true"/>
    </file:inbound-endpoint> 
    <mulexml:dom-to-xml-transformer doc:name="DOM to XML"/>
    <set-property propertyName="Content-Type" value="application/xml" doc:name="Property"/>
    <logger message="Payload #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```

Answer (score 0):

What it sounds like you're trying to do is call a file on demand. The file inbound endpoint will be no good for this because, as you say, it constantly polls a directory.

Try replacing your file endpoint in your second flow with the [Mule Requestor Module](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule-module-requester). This plugin allows you to call a resource on demand - I've used this many times myself and it comes in very handy. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, yes you are right we cannot use File inbound component here.

Answer (score 0):

In that scenario, I think you could try the [HTTP Static Resource Handler](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/HTTP+Static+Resource+Handler).

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution, we have to use Parse-Template component of mule, which helps in rendering static content.

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Parse+Template+Reference